# switch(...) in Update() or constructor?

Tags: class, enums, xna

I'm trying to make my first real game in XNA...
I've made an `Abilities` class which keeps track of different abilities a monster or item can have...
I also made an enumeration of all the kinds of abilities I want. 
I was wondering...
Would it be better to have just a `TypeOfAbility` field in my class and a big `switch(TypeOfAbility)` in my `Update()` method which would check the type every time and act accordingly, or have a lot of fields, a big `switch(TypeOfAbility)` in the class constructor, which would set the values of the fields and an `Update()` method which would use all the fields and no big 'switch(TypeOfAbility)'?
Maybe a combination of the above?...
Anyway, thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It sounds like you're attempting to reimplement subtype polymorphism.  Why not create a set of classes that inherit from a base `Ability` class, each of which is responsible for implementing the logic for a different ability?

Comment: Hmm... That's quite a good idea! Thanks, I'll definitely consider it!